# AWS CDK: NaN.NaN.NaN.NaN is not a valid IP Address when creating Client VPN Endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

When trying to create a client vpn resource, I get the following error:

```
Error: NaN.NaN.NaN.NaN is not a valid IP Address
      at NetworkUtils.numToIp (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\jsii-kernel-mj0Ij1\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-ec2\lib\network-util.js:80:19)
      at CidrBlock.minIp (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\jsii-kernel-mj0Ij1\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-ec2\lib\network-util.js:202:29)
      at new CidrBlock (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\jsii-kernel-mj0Ij1\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-ec2\lib\network-util.js:189:29)
      at new ClientVpnEndpoint (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\jsii-kernel-mj0Ij1\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-ec2\lib\client-vpn-endpoint.js:133:29)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\cdk\networking\client_vpn_stack.py", line 95, in __init__        
    client_vpn = ec2.ClientVpnEndpoint(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is the code (all the other resources such as the VPC are created earlier in the code):

```py
from aws_cdk import aws_ec2 as ec2

client_vpn = ec2.ClientVpnEndpoint(
    self,
    id='ClientVPNEndpoint',
    description=f'Client VPN in VPC - {vpc.attr_vpc_id}',

    # Networking
    split_tunnel=True,
    cidr='172.16.0.0/16',
    vpc=vpc,
    port=ec2.VpnPort.HTTPS,
    session_timeout=ec2.ClientVpnSessionTimeout.TEN_HOURS,

    # Security
    server_certificate_arn=f'arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:{self.account}:certificate/{certificate_id}',
    security_groups=[sg],
    user_based_authentication=ec2.ClientVpnUserBasedAuthentication.federated(
        saml_provider=saml_provider
    )
)
```

The only IP I can think of is the cidr but from the documentation they except a cidr block of the format X.X.X.X/X.

I tried to replace the cidr with other values, but nothing helped...

Can anyone help me what is missing here?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Edit

VPC range: 10.1.0.0/16 (defined in another stack but passed by value in the same app)

I tried using /22 and /16 for the client VPN CIDR block, this didn't change anything.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/ClientVpnEndpoint.html) - "The CIDR block should be /22 or greater".  Have you tried that?  And what else is in `self`?

Comment: Is there any investigation regarding this?
`The address range cannot overlap with the target network address range, the VPC address range or any of the routes that will be associated with the Client VPN endpoint. The client address range must be at minimum /22 and not greater than /12 CIDR block size. You cannot change the client address range after you create the Client VPN endpoint.`

Comment: @stdunbar /16 is greater than /22 so I think everything is fine on that regard.

Comment: @ScottHsieh The VPC range is 10.1.0.0/16. I on purpose chose 172.x.x.x/x to avoid collision.

Comment: Can you provide a complete minimal stack that we could synth and reproduce the issue?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad...

The `vpc` variable in use was of type `ec2.CfnVPC`. The compiler couldn't find required fields contained in `ec2.IVpc` and returned an error.
Although I should have read the documentation more carefully, the error message wasn't quite clear.

This is the constructor from the documentation:

> ```py
> class ClientVpnEndpoint(
>     scope: Construct,
>     id: str,
>     *,
>     vpc: IVpc,
>     cidr: str,
>     server_certificate_arn: str,
>     authorize_all_users_to_vpc_cidr: bool | None = None,
>     client_certificate_arn: str | None = None,
>     client_connection_handler: IClientVpnConnectionHandler | None = None,
>     client_login_banner: str | None = None,
>     description: str | None = None,
>     dns_servers: Sequence[str] | None = None,
>     logging: bool | None = None,
>     log_group: ILogGroup | None = None,
>     log_stream: ILogStream | None = None,
>     port: VpnPort | None = None,
>     security_groups: Sequence[ISecurityGroup] | None = None,
>     self_service_portal: bool | None = None,
>     session_timeout: ClientVpnSessionTimeout | None = None,
>     split_tunnel: bool | None = None,
>     transport_protocol: TransportProtocol | None = None,
>     user_based_authentication: ClientVpnUserBasedAuthentication | None = None,
>     vpc_subnets: SubnetSelection | Dict[str, Any] | None = None
> )
> ```

This is the full stack if someone is interested:

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    Tags,
    aws_ec2 as ec2,
    aws_iam as iam
)

# Client VPN Endpoint
saml_provider = iam.SamlProvider.from_saml_provider_arn(
    self,
    id='IdP',
    saml_provider_arn=f'arn:aws:iam::{self.account}:saml-provider/{identity_provider_id}'
)

client_vpn = ec2.ClientVpnEndpoint(
    self,
    id='ClientVpn',
    description=f'Client VPN Endpoint',

    # Networking
    vpc=vpc,
    vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
        subnets=clientvpn_subnets
    ),
    cidr=clientvpn_cidr_block,
    port=ec2.VpnPort.HTTPS,
    split_tunnel=True,
    transport_protocol=ec2.TransportProtocol.TCP,
    session_timeout=ec2.ClientVpnSessionTimeout.TEN_HOURS,

    # Security
    server_certificate_arn=f'arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:{self.account}:certificate/{certificate_id}',
    security_groups=[sg],
    user_based_authentication=ec2.ClientVpnUserBasedAuthentication.federated(
        saml_provider=saml_provider
    ),
    authorize_all_users_to_vpc_cidr=False,

    # Logging
    logging=True,
    log_group=log_group,
    log_stream=log_stream
)

client_vpn.add_authorization_rule(
    id='AuthorizationRule',
    description='Authorize all private ip range to everyone',
    cidr='10.0.0.0/8'
)
```

Comment: Your IDE should have shown you an error about passing an incorrect type.